# Are solitons an example of collective motion?

Tags: solitons

Are [solitons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soliton) an example of collective motion?

Comment: why -1?????????

Answer (score 2):

"soliton" is a general term that covers a multitude of evils.

If your soliton is a water wave then yes it's obviously formed by the collective motion of water molecules. If the soliton is a solution to the QCD equations of motion then no it's not an example of collection motion.